# Does there exist a tool for combining java files

Tags: java

I am joining a competition that requires me to put all my java classes in one single .java file. Does there exist a tool that does this for me (including changing the visibility of classes to be able to do this)?

**Addition**: thanks for trying to help me to read the site of the competition but I quote:

> It is possible to make more than one
>   class for your program, but you will
>   have to put the source for all classes
>   in a single .java file (the compiler
>   will produce multiple .class files
>   anyway). When you do this, you should
>   not declare your classes public, or
>   the compiler will complain about it.

So, only 1 .java file is allowed (no jar) and in that file I can have multiple non-public classes besides my public main class (and not only static inner classes as suggested).

Comment: Its not preferable to do, So i don't think any org has spent time on that.

Comment: @org.life.java I was already afraid for that...

Comment: I would like to know that why you want to do this?

Comment: @org.life.java I am joining a competition (http://codecup.nl) that requires me to submit my solution in a single java file

Comment: then you can manually copy and paste all the classes in one single java file with taking care of access specifiers. i hope as its competition it won't be more than 5 class.

Comment: @org.life.java Yeah, that's what I'm doing now, but I would like to automate this as I am submitting a new version every 2 weeks (it's btw around 10 classes)

Comment: @org.live.java I have no idea, I'm joining it for fun :)

Comment: Side note: Make sure you only have one `public` class.

Comment: Sure they did not mean single jar file? :)

Comment: @willcodejavaforfood: I originally asked that in a comment, but the site actually says a single .java file, so I deleted said comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have access to Unix-y shell (for Windows, you can install e.g. Git for a decent Bash implementation, *and* it gives you a great VC tool):

```
cat *.java | sed 's/public class/class/g' >AllTehCodez.java
```

Doesn't have to be more complicated than that (unless you have a lot of strings containing the substring "public class", of course).

**Edit:** Doesn't work for package and imports. But...

```
(
  egrep -h ^package *.java | head -1
  egrep -h ^import *.java | sort -u
  egrep -hv '^(import|package)' *.java | sed 's/public class/class/g' 
) >AllTehCodez.java
```

This does of course assume all the classes are in the same package.

Comment: close - package and import declarations kill that solution. You'll have to edit the result after the merge.

Answer (score 0):

If we exclude various "bijou scripting haquettes" along the lines suggested above, I seriously doubt that any serious tool exists for doing this.

Why?  Because this kind of nonsense goes against all known Java style rules and conventions!

The people behind that website need to be taught about archive file formats; e.g. TAR, ZIP, JAR.

**EDIT**

I take that back.  They DO understand JAR files. Quoting from one of their documents:

> **Using your own executable Java jar with Caia**
>
> You can also use your own Java jar in
>   Caia competitions. We have written the
>   jarwrapper for that. The source of
>   jarwrapper.c is put in the
>   caia_install_/jarwrapper/
>   folder. In the Windows distro this is
>   put into the src/ folder.
>
> Suppose the name of your class file is
>   JavaPlayer.class. The only thing you
>   will have to do is to rename the
>   executable in the bin/ folder from
>   jarwrapper to JavaPlayer. The
>   executable now will perform the
>   command: java -jar JavaPlayer. The jar
>   file should contain a manifest which
>   points to the class with the main
>   method.
>
> In manager.txt you can use the program
>   name JavaPlayer which refers to the
>   executable that starts your Java jar
>   player.

Comment: Yes, their software supports it, but for the real competition there is clearly in the rules that it must be a single .java source file. Note that they want source files, and that the part you quoted now is about compiled files (java -jar)